# Deploying site on Shared Hosting using fastcgi

Tags: python, django, apache, fastcgi

I am trying to deploy the site on shared-hosting called "dreamhost" on their Debian VPS.
I have followed [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/?from=olddocs#apache-shared-hosting)
When i visit the server ip in browser i am having following error:

```
The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

i have a project in `/home/user_name/project/` i have created two files in this directory.

**.htacess**

```
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

**dispatch.fcgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(1, '/home/user_name/project')

# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "project.path.to.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

I have executed the `./dispatch.fcgi` and it shows site home page in terminal. How ever nothing works when i try to access in browser, always got 404 error. `hello.fcgi` script also giving 404 error.
I have tried all techniques but nothing is really working :(

Answer (score 0):

Dreamhost has instructions for installing Django using WSGI, FastCGI, or any other method you want. Look it up on their wiki. I think the address is http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Django.
**Update:** (I can't add comments on my computer for some reason) Did you try mod_wsgi instead?

Comment: I have at first followed the same instruction listed in http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Django_FastCGI but again fail

Comment: Use their instruction for **WSGI** recommended by Dreamhost.